# EF Code first join based on a range

Tags: entity-framework, join

I am using EF v6 Code First against an existing SQL DB (so the schema is fairly fixed).

I need to build a model for the following classes and wanted to know if there is a was a way to map a relationship between a Reading and a TemperatureCategory where the Reading's temperature falls between the lower and upper bounds of the TemperatureCategory?

```
public class Reading
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public double Temperature { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual TemperatureCategory Category { get; set; }
}

public class TemperatureCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double LowerBound { get; set; }
    public double UpperBound { get; set; }
    ...          
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interesting idea, but no, you can't. Joins are always based on equality.

So you have to query the `TemperatureCategory`. For instance

```
from r in context.Readings
let category = context.TemperatureCategories
                      .FirstOrDefault(c => c.LowerBound < r.Temperature
                                        && c.UpperBound >= r.Temperature)
select new { Reading = r, Category = category.Description }
```